# Redirect a page if timestamp in URL string is expired

Tags: php, string, url, redirect, timestamp

I've pieced together some code by looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789025/how-to-redirect-users-based-on-random-url-string) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493167/display-content-based-on-date-with-php). But I didn't quite get it.

I want to include a timestamp in my url and check to see if 2 months has passed from the timestamp. If we are within the 2 months, display the page normally. If more than 2 months has passed, redirect the page.

Here's what I have so far but it's not working. Any suggestions on how I can get this working properly?

```
//test timestamp... this will come from the url as so: www.mywebsite.com?ts=1340037073
$timestamp = echo $_GET['ts'];

//check if it has expired (in seconds, 5256000 sec = 2 months).
if ((time() - $timestamp) < 5256000)
{
echo 'valid';
}
else
{
Header("Location: http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: so... What are you looking for? :D

Comment: Which is your question ??

Comment: Right. Sorry. My question is: how do I modify the code so that it works?

Answer (score 1):

The code to calculate the difference between the timestamps should work if you remove the "echo" from line #2; i.e. change:

$timestamp = echo $_GET['ts'];

to

$timestamp = $_GET['ts'];

You also may want test isset($_GET['ts']) and handle that condition explicitly since its possible to enter the page without the 'ts' variable being set.

Comment: add_action( 'wp', 'registration_discount');
    function registration_discount(){
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/registration-discount') {
    if(isset($_GET['ts'])){
    if ((time() - $timestamp) >= 5256000){
    {
    echo 'valid';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.funkytownusa.com">'
    }

Answer (score 0):

So based on these comments and others, I've modified the code to this and it's working:

```
// Registration Discount Page
//check if it has expired (in seconds, 5256000 sec = 2 months).
add_action( 'wp', 'registration_discount');
function registration_discount(){
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/registration-discount') > -1 ){
    if(empty($_GET['ts'])){
        header("location: http://www.funkytownusa.com");
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['ts'])){
        if ((time() - $_GET['ts']) >= (DAY_IN_SECONDS * 60))
        {
            header("location: http://www.funkytownusa.com");
        }
    }
  }
}
```